# Generic Iterator implementation in java

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I have the following design:
I have an Abstract class `Instance`,
I have a class `Library` that extends `Instance` and
I have a class `File` that also extends Instance

I've created my own linked list implementation and it's defined as follows:

```
public class List<T extends Instance> implements Iterable {
    //some other code here

     public Iterator iterator(){
         return new ListIterator(this);

}
```

now I've created a class

```
public class ListIterator<T extends Instance> implements Iterator<T> {
    private List thisList;
    private Node current;

    public ListIterator(List l){
        thisList=l;
        current=thisList.head.next;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(current==null)
            return false;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        Node temp=current;
        current=current.next;
        return temp.data;
    }
}
```

Where `Node` is

```
public class Node<T extends Instance> {
    public Node<T> next;
    public Node<T> prev;
    public T data;

    public Node(T data,Node prev, Node next){
        this.data=data;
        this.prev=prev;
        this.next=next;
    }   
}
```

so my problem is as follows: the line return temp.data rises an error:

> Type mismatch - cannot convert from Instance to T.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: It'll be easier to figure out what's happening if you post the code of the Node class.  Also... this isn't... _homework_, is it?

Comment: Because (1) if it's not for homework (or at least, private study) then it's probably a bad idea to implement List yourself, and (2) if it _were_ for homework then we should be helping you to learn from the error, rather than giving you the answer in a can.

Comment: Btw if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ etc, turn on the option to warn you when you're using raw types instead of generics. It'll give you an extra pointer with this kind of problem.  (Though if you get heavily into generics, you'll also come across some warnings you can't get rid of. Generics are a pain.)

Comment: One more tip - then I'll stop bugging you - read Josh Bloch's Effective Java, which contains an item explaining (far more eloquently than I could) why you shouldn't be writing your own List - except as a learning exercise, of course. Josh Bloch, by the way, was one of the engineers who wrote Java's Collections API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that `Node.data` is a reference to an `Instance` object? If that is the case, the compiler can't automatically change an `Instance` to a `T`, because even though `T` is an `Instance` object (`T extends Instance`), any given `Instance` might not be a `T`.

The Java Generics tutorial explains it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

Also, in your `List<T>` class, you should be specifying `Iterator` and `ListIterator` as generic using `Iterator<T>` and `ListIterator<T>`, or else the compiler won't be able to handle the generics properly. Your `Node` reference also needs to be generic: `Node<T>`

Hence you should be using

```
private Node<T> current;
```

and

```
public T next() {
    Node<T> temp=current;
    current=current.next;
    return temp.data;
}
```

The compiler will usually warn you when you're using a raw type for a generic class.

Comment: Node.data is of type T and T extends Instance

Comment: I've updated my answer: you will need to specify Node as Node<T> or else it will be treated as untyped (and hence is of type Instance, not T)

Comment: I think that's the answer the OP wanted.  Mine was just wilfully literal-minded.

Answer (score 1):

Did no one notice the bug:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    if(current==null)
        return false;
    return false;
}
```

This is an invariant. Unless I am missing something, the iterator will very quickly return 0 elements!